# $\int_0^{\infty} \frac {x.dx}{(x^2+a^2)^{\frac 32}(x^2+b^2)} $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am solving a problem where I need to find the charge distribution on a conducting plate, and the field due to it. I'm stuck on this integral.
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac {x.dx}{(x^2+a^2)^{\frac 32}(x^2+b^2)} $$

Comment: A substitution $u=x^2$ seems like a good start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

*(I leave the intermediate steps for you as an exercise)*

First substitute $u = \sqrt{x^2 + a^2}\implies\mathrm dx = \dfrac{\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}}x\,\mathrm du$.

$$\int\dfrac{x}{\left(x^2 + a^2\right)^{3/2}\left(x^2 + b^2\right)}\,\mathrm dx\equiv\int\dfrac{1}{u^2\left(u^2 + b^2 - a^2\right)}\,\mathrm du$$

Next, perform partial fraction decomposition.

$$\int\dfrac{1}{u^2\left(u^2 + b^2 - a^2\right)}\,\mathrm du\equiv\dfrac{1}{b^2 - a^2}\int\dfrac{1}{u^2}\,\mathrm du - \dfrac{1}{b^2 - a^2}\int\dfrac{1}{u^2 + b^2 - a^2}\,\mathrm du$$

Finally, substitute $v = \dfrac{u}{\sqrt{b^2 - a^2}}\implies\mathrm du = \sqrt{b^2 - a^2}\,\mathrm dv$.

Can you take it from here?